# Typescript Dictionary Coding of Effective Javascript dict function into class

Tags: javascript, dictionary, typescript

What would be a good Typescript class derived from the example in "Effective Javascript" dict example

    `function Dict(elements) {
        // allow an optional initial table
        this.elements = elements || {}; // simple Object
        this.hasSpecialProto = false; // has "__proto__" key?
        this.specialProto = undefined; // "__proto__" element
    }
        Dict.prototype.has = function (key) {
        if (key === "__proto__") {
            return this.hasSpecialProto;
        }
        // own property only
        return {}.hasOwnProperty.call(this.elements, key);
    };
    Dict.prototype.get = function (key) {
        if (key === "__proto__") {
            return this.specialProto;
        }
        // own property only
        return this.has(key)
            ? this.elements[key]
            : undefined;
    };
    Dict.prototype.set = function (key, val) {
        if (key === "__proto__") {
            this.hasSpecialProto = true;
            this.specialProto = val;
        } else {
            this.elements[key] = val;
        }
     };
    Dict.prototype.remove = function (key) {
        if (key === "__proto__") {
            this.hasSpecialProto = false;
            this.specialProto = undefined;
        } else {
            delete this.elements[key];
        }
    };`

The bot wants me to enter more explanation which I would regard as verbosity. Who knows when I will type enough to please it. It also wants me to indent things perfectly, too.

Comment: I know the book you refer to, but can you elaborate why they do this stuff to `__proto__`? The prototype property as shown here should not be accessed in that way, and such use should be avoided. I refer to ES specifications. Only way to get the prototype link is by calling `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`.

Comment: From the book Effective JS, "Use a dictionary class to protect against the use of "__proto__" as
a key", p.122; end of "Tip 45".

Comment: aha okay, it is about protecting **proto**, that makes sense in conjunction with what I said, thank you! (I don't have the book at hand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your original code is correct. The following is the code transformed to TypeScript:

```
class Dict {
    hasSpecialProto = false; // has "__proto__" key?
    specialProto = undefined; // "__proto__" element

    constructor(public elements = {}) {
        // allow an optional initial table        

    }

    has(key) {
        if (key === "__proto__") {
            return this.hasSpecialProto;
        }
        // own property only
        return {}.hasOwnProperty.call(this.elements, key);
    }

    get(key) {
        if (key === "__proto__") {
            return this.specialProto;
        }
        // own property only
        return this.has(key)
            ? this.elements[key]
            : undefined;
    }

    set(key, val) {
        if (key === "__proto__") {
            this.hasSpecialProto = true;
            this.specialProto = val;
        } else {
            this.elements[key] = val;
        }
    }

    remove(key) {
        if (key === "__proto__") {
            this.hasSpecialProto = false;
            this.specialProto = undefined;
        } else {
            delete this.elements[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Note that TypeScript will know what `this` means in the functions + I used a default parameter in the constructor.

If you are looking for something more powerful (and tested) with generics take a look at TypeScript collections : https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections#included-data-structures

Comment: I would add return value types to the methods, because without it the return values would be of type `void` and if called from Typescript this would not compile: `var hasTest: boolean = dict.has("test");`